# how to config vscode prettier format force line wrap

Tags: visual-studio-code, line, prettier

my vscode settings:

```
"prettier.printWidth": 100,
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
```

my source code:

```
if (200 != response.status)
    return '';
```

the prettier format it to(it seems ugly):

```
if (200 != response.status) return '';
```

how to force line wrap (force format two line)?

Answer (score 2):

The universal answer to questions like "How can I make Prettier format my code in such a way that ...?" is "You can't."

Prettier's purpose is to facilitate collaboration in projects and teams by taking care of code style, not to be a customizable code formatter that does whatever the user wants. In other words, the formatting it produces isn't really customizable, and this is intentional. Read more [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). If you need that degree of control over formatting, you're likely not the target audience for Prettier.

That said, Prettier sometimes (if the line is long enough) produces the formatting you want. However, this style is [considered problematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code#goto_fail_bug) and for this reason is likely to change in future versions.

Comment: thanks for your reply. any other format tool suggestion?

Comment: I'd say you care too much about those ifs. Don't step over dollars to chase pennies.